# Uncommanded Logout during Photos initial upload to iCloud Photo Library

Tags: icloud, photos.app

I am performing the initial long upload of my local Photos photo library to iCloud photo library. However, when I leave my computer on with the Photos app open for a couple hours, my computer seems to try to logout and, in the attempt, it tries to quit Photos. when I return to my computer, I see the message:

"Photos" interrupted logout.
To continue logging out, quit "Photos".

Unlike the help documentation that shows up when I type this error into google, I don't want my computer to sleep, logout, or shutdown. As such, I have my system settings set as such. (I have confirmed my computer is set to not sleep, screensaver, logout, or shutdown due to inactivity.) I am therefore confused as to what is going on here and need it to stop. I want to leave my computer alone for long periods to concentrate on uploading my photo library. This problem seems to prevent the upload from occurring.

Edit: It is very possible that this error occurs after a consistent period of time. However, All system settings are set to never sleep, screen saver, etc... So I don't know where said specific period of time is coming from.

Comment: Did you check System Preferences > Energy Saver > Schedule ... to make sure there is no scheduled shutdown time set?

Comment: Just checked it. There is no schedule of any kind set. Also, this symptom happens whenever Photos is left open and the computer unattended for a few hours. The time of day does not matter. Thank you for the response though.

Comment: Are there are other users logged into this Mac through fast user switching?

Comment: No. I am the only user logged in. I have a different user account that can be logged into on this computer, but I have not logged into that user for about a year.

Comment: In Terminal type `pmset -g sched`. Is there a result?

Comment: There is no result. It just prompts with the same text again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79106/discussion-between-icondaemon-and-uniqueworldline).